# Orion Context Broker and identity managment

Tags: fiware-orion

We plan to implement mobile apps and web apps communicating with Orion instance hosted on a virtual server provided by a commercial provider (e.g. Amazon). Do you think it is a good idea to use Orion Context Broker and KeyRock Identity Manager together? What are other options for identity management and security in systems based on Orion?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PEP Proxy](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion-pep).

It's purpose is to make communications with enablers more secure using both the Identity Manager and Access Control GEs

Answer (score 0):

The PEP Proxy is one of the pieces of the Authorization, Authentication and Identity Management proposed by FIWARE.

The Identity Management is currently based on Keyrock. The situation just now is that some of the pieces are in a process of changing, so you may either use the current solution based on Keyrock or the future one based on Openstack's Keystone (with some contributed extensions adding SCIM and OAuth 2.0 support).

FIWARE authorization is based on the XACML model (https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xacml/) that defines two kinds of components: an authorization server (PAP + PDP in the XACML document) corresponding to the Access Control FIWARE GE (or similarly Telefonica's Keypass Access Control) and the PEP Proxy whose goal is to intercept every request coming to a component to evaluate its permissions asking both the IDM and the Access Control (the one pointed out by @LGM, based on the future Keyston's version or the one based to KeyRock, https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-pep-proxy, are examples of PEP Proxies).

Summarizing, Context Broker and the Identity Management and Authorization solutions of FIWARE are meant to be used together, but you will have to choose between using the old version based on KeyRock now and using the newer one based on Keystone once its available (information about it is supposed to be about to be released).